# Tools to visualize a Spark GraphX graph with 800 million vertices and 2 billion edges

Tags: spark-graphx, graph-visualization, jgraphx

We have a large graph processed with Spark GraphX having about 800 million nodes and 2 billion vertices.

Are there any tool which allows visualization of the data. The data is currently stored in s3 and its capacity is about 600 GB. I checked into tools like Gephi, Graphlab etc but not sure if they will be able to handle this amount of data.

Comment: That's an interesting question. I'm working on a large graph (billions of vertices/edges) and sometimes in needs to visualize a part of that graph, but so far, was not convinced on tested solutions.